# broadleaf payment response page not shown

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, authorize.net, broadleaf-commerce

We have integrated the broadleaf commerce application with authorize.net developer account(**sandbox**) for payment processing. Using [Broadleaf - Authorize.net Environment Setup](http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/authorizenet/current/authorize.net-environment-setup)
When we do a checkout and card payment, we are able to fill in the card details, and submit the form, which makes the payment processing, but getting a white page response on the browser saying

```
An error occurred while trying to report this transaction to the merchant. An e-mail has been sent to the merchant informing them of the error. The following is the result of the attempt to charge your credit card.

This transaction has been approved.

It is advisable for you to contact the merchant to verify that you will receive the product or service.
```

With URL : https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll

How can I make the response get displayed on the actual broadleaf display?
Or do we need to do any implementations for displaying the response?

Using broadleaf version : **3.1.8-GA**

Error screen shown below: 
[image: screen shown with the error message]

Comment: This error indicates that the Authorize.Net server is unable to POST to your relay response URL configured in your properties file.  It must be publicly available and on a standard port 80 or 443.

Comment: I was running the app on my local with publishing my the server **publically**, using ngrok(https://ngrok.com). Let me try again hosting the app on a public server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rhldr was right. 
It must be publicly available and on a standard port 80 or 443.